# what is the function that is called when the app is appearing?

Tags: ios, loading, viewwillappear

Imagine the app is running and you press the iphone button (the phone button) and you exit the app. then you tap on the app again to enter the app. My problem is that when ever the user does this I want the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear functions to be called, but unfortunately none of these functions gets called.

I want to know if these function won't get called, then what is the function that is called when the app is appearing again?

Comment: the delegates: -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application, -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application in AppDelegate.m file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` in your `UIApplicationDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at UIApplicationDelegate.  -applicationDidBecomeActive: is what you are looking for.

You can also register for notifications in your classes (UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification).  This may be simpler to implement than having your app delegate handle everything since you can have, for example, each view controller manage itself.

(Use NSNotificationCenter's -addObserver:selector:name:object: to register, don't forget to unregister during object cleanup, typically in -dealloc.)